# Prove that $\sqrt[m]{n}$ is either a positive integer or irrational for positive integers $m,n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, irrational-numbers

Just need a verification of my proof.

*Proof.*

Naturally, there arises two cases.

*Case 1:* $n = a^m$ for some $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Clearly, $\sqrt[m]{n} = \sqrt[m]{a^m} = a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

*Case 2:* Otherwise.

Suppose that $\sqrt[m]{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$. This would mean that $\exists p,q \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\sqrt[m]{n} = \frac{p}{q}$ under the conditions that $q \nmid p$ and $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ (otherwise, just simplify).

So, $\sqrt[m]{n} = \frac{p}{q} \implies n = \frac{p^m}{q^m} \implies p^m = nq^m$. Now, notice that by definition of divisibility, $n \mid p^m$. If $n$ is prime, then it follows that $n \mid p$. So, $p = nk_1$ for some positive integer $k_1 \implies (nk_1)^m = nq^m \implies n^{m-1}k_1^m = q^m$. Since $m \geq 2$ (if $m=1$, then $\sqrt[m]{n} = n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$), we have that $m - 1 \geq 1$, so $n \mid q^m$.

Since $n$ is prime, we have that $n \mid q$. But this is a contradiction, since it was assumed that $p,q$ were co-prime but we have just demonstrated that $p,q$ share a common factor of $n$.

Now, if $n$ is not prime, find some prime $p_1$ such that $p_1 \mid n$ (the existence of such a prime is guaranteed by the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic). Then, $p_1 \mid p^m$ (since $p_1 \mid n$)  $\implies p_1 \mid p$. Thus, by the definition of divisibility, $p = p_1k_2$ for some $k_2 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. So, making the substitution,

$(p_1k_2)^m = nq^m \implies (p_1k_2)^m = (p_1k_3)q^m$ (since $p_1 \mid n)$ for some $k_3 \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. So, $p_1^{m-1}k_2^m = k_3q^m$.

Using same type of argument as previously, since $m \geq 2, p \mid q^m \implies p \mid q$. Now the contradiction is at hand as $p,q$ share a common factor. QED.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks fine to me. You could make it shorter by using a prime divisor of $n$ from the beginning thus avoiding the duplication.

Comment: Or use this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example $m=2$ and $n=18$.  Since $n$ is not prime, you want $p_1\mid n$, say $p_1=3$.  Following your argument gives $3\mid p$ and $k_3=6$, and your final equation is
$$3k_2^2=6q^2\ .$$
This does not prove that $3\mid q$ and so you have no contradiction.

Of course this is easy to fix **in this particular case** - just take $p_1=2$ instead of $p_1=3$.  But you need to work out how to make sure you can do something similar when $n$ is unspecified.

Also consider a case like $m=2$, $n=27$.  This is possibly even a bit harder.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I wonder how I can wisely restrict my choice of p_1 to make it work (in the general case)?

Answer (score 1):

Most of it seems fine, but I agree with the other anwerer that I don't see how $p_1^{m-1}k_2^m = k_3q^m$ implies that $p \mid q^m$, while it does indeed imply that $p_1 \mid k_3q^m$

I'd also like to bring attetion to this part:

$\sqrt[m]{n} = \frac{p}{q} \implies n = \frac{p^m}{q^m}$

I believe this should be enough for your proof, since

$n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \implies \frac{p^m}{q^m} \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \implies q^m \mid p^m$

Since $gcd(p,q) = 1$, that means $q^m = 1 \implies q = 1 \implies \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Z} \implies \sqrt[m]{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response. I believe I have made a typo, instead of p, I should have written p_1. Then p_1 should divide (k_3)(q^m) - as you have mentioned. But since p_1 divides n, I wonder if I can make the conclusion that p_1 mustn't divide k_3? Hence, p_1 must divide q^m. I can then proceed as I did as in my question. My intention was to make use of Euclid's Lemma.

Comment: I don't think you can make the conclusion that $p_1$ doesn't divide $k_3$. Take a look at the example in David's answer, where $p_1 = 3$ and $k_3 = 6$, so $p_1 \mid k_3$.